# How to identify which IFRAME is which?

Tags: javascript, html

How to refer to a component inside an `IFRAME` is showed in [this reply](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?147118-Access-Components-in-an-iframe). It works under the assumption that there's only one `IFRAME` (or that we are certain that the zero-th will suffice). However, I wonder how to identify the actual `IFRAME` I'd like to poke.

I need the syntax for changing:

```
window.frames[0].document. + my stuff
```

into something like:

```
window.frames["theIdOfMyIFrame"].document. + my stuff
```

but I can't get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would avoid using *window.frames*. (Might be due to the lack of experience with them.)
2. When a reply on the net is on form *something[0]*, be cautious. Bad coding style, **probably**.
3. The reference to your *theIdOfMyIFrame* should be used.
4. The inner document is right under *contentDocument*.

You can refer to the embedded components like this.

```javascript
document.getElementById("theIdOfMyIFrame")
  .contentDocument.getElementById("controlIdInTheembeddedPage")
    .value = "Christophe has eyes for details!";
```

Comment: After I've read the discussion above, I took the liberty of changing in your answer.

Comment: @konrad-viltersten this answer is ok, but based on your other comments you seem to be confused about iframes. They are not abandoned in html5, on the contrary they are getting much more powerful.

Comment: @Christophe Now you're just showing-off. :D   Nevertheless, I'm the first dude to admit when I'm mistaken. Which I apparently was.

Comment: Actually the code in this answer doesn't look right, it should be getElementById("theIdOfMyIFrame").contentDocument and not the other way around.

Comment: @Christophe Corrected the error. Now, I claim it's perfect (until something more is found).

Comment: well, I might mention cross-browser compatibility, but you'll say that I'm showing off ;-) Think about it though...

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with this problem earlier.

If you show the response of a cross-site request in an iframe, the new browsers are denying the access to this iframe, because of the same-origin policy or cross-site scripting/request prohibition.
For more information see here: [IFrame Permission Denied](http://davidwalsh.name/iframe-permission-denied)

If you want to dynamically add content, this solution might help you: [Add Dynamic Content](http://thomas.bindzus.me/2007/12/24/adding-dynamic-contents-to-iframes/)

Best regards

Comment: Actually, both files are at the moment locally placed so the URL is *file://something*. But it's good to get some heads-up for the upcoming issue of cross site scripting. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Some days ago I wanted to post a file without reloading the page, and then I ran into this problem. Always expect the unexpected. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById` instead of the nasty deprecated `window.frames` property:

```
document.getElementById("theIdOfMyIFrame").contentDocument ...
```

Comment: Whoops, forgot that you need `contentDocument` here.

Comment: You forgot *contentDocument*. Embarassing, Dusky... :D

Comment: How comes it that you think that `window.frames` is deprecated? That is a wrong info you got there...

Comment: @Christoph Because it's not supposed to be used anymore? IFRAME has been abandoned in HTML5.

Comment: You are confusing some things. Framesets are deprecated, iframes however are not and neither is the window property frames.

Comment: `window.frames` is a [DOM0](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/dom0.html) property. While I suppose they aren't *officially* deprecated, they've never been part of any official specification, and they're far less general than the "official" DOM methods like `getElementById`.

Comment: 1)dom0 is supported by every browser. 2) of course dom 0 has never been officially specified because it was introduced together with Javascript in Netscape 2 in 95 when the w3c had just recently been founded, which at a later point started to standardize ecmascript and the dom. however that has no impact on the importance of dom 0.